# mysql delete query with condition

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query .. Delete in more than one table .. but If there a field does not have content in any table, it does not delete anything

```
$sql = " DELETE 
            property,
            unit,
            maintenance,
            report,
            owner
         FROM 
            property,
            unit,
            maintenance,
            report,
            owner           
        WHERE 
            property.id = '".$_REQUEST['property']."'
        AND
            unit.property = property.id
        AND
            unit.id = maintenance.unitid
        AND 
            report.maintenance = maintenance.id 
        AND 
            property.id = owner.property 
        ";
```

SO , what conditions can i use it in the query to skip this problem ..

Comment: the table names between `DELETE` and `FROM` should not be there. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look at [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) for this. This is a typical (but costly ) way to perform this kind of operation.

Alternatively, you could create a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) and check that all the criteria are appropriate before executing the delete.